# Spring Boot + Shiro + Thymleaf

Tags: css, spring

I have some problems with my webapp. Here is my code:

Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"app.controllers", "app.service"})
public class MainStConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = { 
            "classpath:/META-INF/resources/",
            "classpath:/resources/", 
            "classpath:/static/", 
            "classpath:/public/", 
            "classpath:/webjars/",
            "classpath:/tempplates/"
    };
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
    }



    @Bean(name = "shiroFilter")
    public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter() {

        ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
        shiroFilter.setLoginUrl("/login.html");
        shiroFilter.setSuccessUrl("/index.html");
        shiroFilter.setUnauthorizedUrl("/index.html?error");


        Map<String, String> filterChain = new HashMap<>(); 
        filterChain.put("/", "anon");
        filterChain.put("/login", "authcBasic");
        filterChain.put("/logout", "logout");
        filterChain.put("/admin/**", "authc,roles[ADMIN]");
        filterChain.put("/student/**", "authc,roles[STUDENT]");
        filterChain.put("/teacher/**", "authc,roles[TEACHER]");
        //filterChain.put("/student/**", "authc,roles[STUDENT]");
        //filterChain.put("/teacher/**", "roles,roles[TEACHER]");

        shiroFilter.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(filterChain);
        shiroFilter.setSecurityManager(securityManager());


        Map<String, Filter> filters = new HashMap<>();
        filters.put("anon", new AnonymousFilter());
        filters.put("authc", new FormAuthenticationFilter());
        filters.put("logout", new LogoutFilter());
        filters.put("roles", new RolesAuthorizationFilter());
        filters.put("user", new UserFilter());
        shiroFilter.setFilters(filters);

        return shiroFilter;
    }
    @Bean
    public org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager securityManager() {

        DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
        securityManager.setRealm(userRealm());

        return securityManager;
    }
    @Bean(name = "userRealm")
    @DependsOn("lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
    public UserRealm userRealm() {
        return new UserRealm();
    }
    @Bean
    public LifecycleBeanPostProcessor lifecycleBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new LifecycleBeanPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

IndexController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String start() {
        return "index";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String index() {
        return "index";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    String login() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

LoginController

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    private Session session;


    @ModelAttribute("userR")
    public User getUser() {
        return new User();
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logoutt() {
        return "redirect:/index";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String admin() {
        return "admin/index";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/student/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String student() {
        return "student/index";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/teacher/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String teacher() {
        return "teacher/index";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(Model model, @ModelAttribute("userR") User user, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs, SessionStatus status) {
        Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        model.addAttribute("login", user.getLogin());

        if (StringUtils.hasText(user.getLogin()) && StringUtils.hasText(user.getPassword())) {
            try {
                UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(user.getLogin(), user.getPassword());

                token.setRememberMe(true);
                currentUser.login(token);
                session = currentUser.getSession(false);

                if(currentUser.hasRole("ADMIN")) {
                    status.setComplete();
                    return "redirect:/admin/index";
                }
                if(currentUser.hasRole("STUDENT")) {
                    status.setComplete();
                    return "redirect:/student/index";
                }
                if(currentUser.hasRole("TEACHER")) {
                    status.setComplete();
                    return "redirect:/teacher/index";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "login";
            }

            return "redirect:index";
        } else {
            return "login";
        }
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.POST)/*@RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.POST)*/
    public String logout() {
        Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();

        try {
            session.stop();
            currentUser.logout();
            return "redirect:/index";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "redirect:/index";
        }
    }
}
```

So, with this code always when I'm starting index page in my console I can see pages without layout with css - white pages without bootstrap but when i change this method i LoginController:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String logout() {
        Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();

        try {
            session.stop();
            currentUser.logout();
            return "redirect:/index";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "redirect:/index";
        }
    }
```

to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

then everything works, I can see all colors etc but here is problem now, When I try to log out, for example from /admin/index then I'm redirecting to /admin/logout with Whitable error. Should be redirecting to index page like without "value = "/logout"" because then it works.

I use fot log out button:

```
<form th:action="@{logout}" method="POST">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info text-center center-block"
                    value="Wyloguj" />
            </form>
```

And when I'm not using this "value = "logout"" then after log out in console I can see this warning:

```
2017-01-06 19:40:56.135  WARN 3400 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'GET' not supported
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why would some one use shiro with Spring boot, and not just Spring security.The first problem sounds like you forgot to add a white-listing so your resources (css etc) are protected by login and the browser gets a 302/401 response when loading them (confirm this using developer tool in your browser)

Comment: I had much problems with configuring spring security. I had this list i first config class. Even after log in I can't see this.

Comment: I check in my browser so I get this : {"timestamp":1483729133952,"status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException","message":"Request method 'GET' not supported","path":"/static/css/mainST.css"}

But I don't know why it is impossible if with adding "value='logout' I can use css ?

Comment: If you have to understand everything that goes on in spring security, I agree it is not easy (I have read most of the code over the last 7 years). If you need a simple Thymeleaf example with Spring security, you are welcome to clone my repo https://bitbucket.org/Klaus_Groenbaek/performance, it has multiple projects, but /stateful is a boilerplate form-based login application (has less than 100 lines of Java code, and some htmls). The code is from a JMeter class I taught a while back.

Comment: I will try it again but I'm not sure that I do it. Maybe someone will help with this problem in shiro and during waiting for that I'll try to configure spring security.

Comment: When I look at the Shinro code it looks like it is not as well integrated into Spring Boot, as Spring security is - take a look at Application.java https://bitbucket.org/Klaus_Groenbaek/performance/src/e7e75907b2b762045121a630061281bbc91bcc45/stateful/src/main/java/dk/groenbaek/stateful/Application.java?at=master it's the entire app.

Comment: If you look at navigation.html, you will also notice that you must post for Logout, and include a CSRF token - I think this is why you get a 405 problem!

Comment: Yes I saw that I'm trying to change shiro to spring security right now. But I see you use inMemoryAuthentication(), how can I do it with MySQL hibernate?

Comment: Do you use JPA or Spring JDBC authentication ?

Comment: You could just run whatever code you like inside the AuthenticationProvider.authenticate method, here the user/pass is just hardcoded

Comment: If you want to use the JDBC realm from Spring security, there is a fairly goor tutorial here https://dzone.com/articles/spring-security-4-authenticate-and-authorize-users - As the tutorial says, you should probably use password hashing. The project has an (above) industry-standard PaswordHasher class you can use.

Comment: Ok Thank you, I will try it :)

Comment: Let me know if you need any assistance.

Comment: Ok thank you I will :) Now I did your sample with spring security "copy-paste" and this works. I will try to integrate with hibernate and my db and then tell how does it works.

Comment: A couple of notes, be aware that all non-get requests will probably require a CRSF token (thymeleaf automatic adds the hidden fields to forms). For password hashing you could use Springs StandardPasswordEncoder, but the default of 1024 hashes is outdated I recommend 100000 times and individual user salt.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have simple problem right now, I don't know how can I redirect after login to 3 different pages depends than user role. I have 3 role(currently in memory user) and 3 home pages for them(admin,student,teacher). Do you have some example link how can I do that?

Comment: Spring controller methods can (autowire) the authentication. I have pushed an update, take a look at the "mateusz" branch, I have change it so admin and studen end on two different pages.

Comment: Not working I've got this warn: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/css/bootstrap.min.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' and on login.html after login this message : There was an error, please try again

Comment: I add role_user which redirect to "home" and when I'm logging to user with role_user then I'm redirecting to admin page

Comment: If it works for admin and student, then you added the new user incorrectly. Double check the auth configuration, or put a breakpoint inside home(..) and see which roles the user has, and why i

Comment: Hello Klaus, could you look at this new problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535377/spring-security-wrong-redirect ?